# DWARF error: mangled line number section when trying to include secext.h in Kotlin/Native cinterop

Tags: kotlin, winapi, kotlin-native, cinterop

I tried including secext.h winapi header in Kotlin/Native cinterop using Gradle:

`build.gradle`:

```
// ...
kotlin {
    mingwX64("windows") {
        compilations.main {
            cinterops {
                secext {
                    packageName 'me.[...].cinterop.secext'

                    includeDirs.allHeaders("src/nativeInterop/cinterop")
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

`src/nativeInterop/cinterop/secext.def`:

```
headers = secext_wrapper.h
headerFilter = secext.h
package = me.[...].cinterop.secext
```

`src/nativeInterop/cinterop/secext_wrapper.h`:

```c
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <security.h>
```

And IDE I use (IntelliJ Idea with the Kotlin plugin) does see the functions from secext.h and it does compile if I don't use any of them. When I try to use `GetUserNameExA`, though, this errors show up in `:linkDebugSharedWindc`:

```
> Task :linkDebugSharedWindows
Produced library API in gpio4k_api.h
e: C:\Users\Chilli\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/clang++ invocation reported errors

The C:\Users\Chilli\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/clang++ command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
C:\Users\Chilli\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1\bin\ld: C:\Users\Chilli\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1\bin\ld: DWARF error: mangled line number section (bad file number)
[many identical lines here]
C:\Users\Chilli\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1\bin\ld: DWARF error: mangled line number section (bad file number)
C:\Users\Chilli\AppData\Local\Temp\konan_temp8580678556601557020\result.o:out:(.text+0x7e4d1): undefined reference to `GetUserNameExA'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

> Task :linkDebugSharedWindows FAILED

Execution failed for task ':linkDebugSharedWindows'.
> Compilation finished with errors
```

And I have literally no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Try to replace the `Secext.h` with `Security.h`, according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexa#requirements).

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT
Security.h is included in secext_wrapper.h. I've also tried to put it into the headerFilter in secext.def but didn't work

Comment: Have you defined `WINAPI_FAMILY`, according to the definition in the header file `Secext.h`,
the function `GetUserNameExA` is only available in Desktop Family or OneCore Family: `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION (WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_SYSTEM)`. try to add `#define WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP` before include the header.

Comment: I did not. I'll check that when I can

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately